# How to enforce a type constructor parameter for GHCI

Tags: haskell, type-parameter, type-constructor

Hello i have the following problem:
I am constructing a parametric `newtype` over a method and i do not know how to explictly tell `GHCI` : `I want you to instiantiate this newtype using this type parameter`

```
 newtype M a = M {fu::a->Int}

 var = M (\s-> length (s:"asa"))  #tell him i want the type parameter to be Char

 b = (fu var) 'c'
```

What i expect to get is : `4`      because `length 'c':"aaa"==4`

What i do  get is :

```
interactive>:118:5: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `A [Char]'
                  with actual type `Ghci30.A [Char]'
      NB: `Ghci30.A' is defined at <interactive>:100:1-25
          `A' is defined at <interactive>:109:1-25
    * In the first argument of `fu', namely `b'
      In the expression: (fu b) "asa"
      In an equation for `it': it = (fu b) "asa"
```

Comment: Hold on, here there is an error on `(fu b) "asa"`, not on `(fu var) 'c'`.

Comment: Sorry i have changed the variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see names like `Ghci30.A [Char]`, this means that you have redefined your type `A` in GHCi. This would not be an issue if you used a proper `.hs` file and reloaded it.

Consider this GHCi session:

```
> data A = A Int
> x = A 2
> data A = A Char  -- redefinition
> :t x
```

What should be the output? The type of `x` is `A`, but it's not the same type `A` having a `Char` inside. GHCi will print the type as

```
x :: Ghci0.A
```

You won't get the error again if you (re-)define `x` after you redefine the type `A`.

If your case, the `x` to be redefined is likely `fu`, which is still referring to the old `A`. Check it with `:t fu`: if it mentions `Ghci30.A`, that's it.

For non trivial definitions, I'd recommend to use a `.hs` file and reload it, so to avoid any trouble.

Comment: This was indeed the problem , but still for visibility purposes can you specify somehow the type parameter that you want ?Something similar to how you use `read` ?  `read t::String`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian If you want to use the old `A` for which you defined `fu`, you probably can use something like `var = Ghci30.M ...`. If you want to use the new `A`, you have to redefine `fu` -- the old definition won't get "ported" to the new type.